# Is it necessary to throw a Splash Potion of Weakness to cure a zombie villager?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it **necessary** to throw a *Splash Potion of Weakness* to a Zombie Villager before feeding it a golden apple? Or is it only needed to weaken it?

Comment: "Or is it only needed to weaken it?" Potion have reverse effects on undead mobs, so a weakness potion would actually make a zombie villager have strength.

Answer (score 6):

As the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie_Villager#Curing) says:

> Zombie villagers can be cured by using a golden apple (regular) on
> them while they are under the effects of Weakness, which can be
> applied by:
>
> - A splash potion of Weakness thrown by the player, a dispenser, or a witch.
> - An area effect cloud of Weakness from a lingering potion.
> - An area effect cloud of Weakness from a creeper explosion.‌
> - A tipped arrow.
> - A command (`/effect @e[type=zombie_villager] weakness`)

Thus, any source of the weakness effect will do, whether or not it comes from a potion.

Comment: So it's indispensable, right?

Comment: @thienvupromc2009 Correct, as ppery pointed out in their answer.